# c# Approaching of variables between for loop and elseif

Tags: c#

Quick question.. I need to reach the instance rand of the random class in the for loop.
Any thing I'm missing to succeed?

```
Console.WriteLine("Seedwaarde (optioneel)");
int s = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

if (s != 0 || s != null)
{

   Random rand = new Random(s);

}
else
{

    Random rand = new Random();

}

for(int i = 0;i < 20; i++){

    rand.next(1, 13);

}
```

Comment: `int` can never be `null`

Comment: Why would you want the user to input a seed value?

Comment: @stuartd Why not? For example, how about a map seed (think Minecraft)?

Comment: @lc. What's the advantage of that over a random seed? (I leave Minecraft to my 7 year old son..) - is it to make the generation repeatable?

Comment: @stuartd If you find a map you like (interesting features, convenient starting point) you can get its seed and share it with other people who can then generate the same map for themselves and play. FWIW, you can check out http://www.minecraftseeds.info/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare `rand` variable in outer scope. I've removed `s != null` check, because `int` cannot be `null`:

```
Console.WriteLine("Seedwaarde (optioneel)");

int s = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
Random rand;

if (s != 0)
{
   rand = new Random(s);
}
else
{
    rand = new Random();
}

for(int i = 0;i < 20; i++){
    rand.next(1, 13);
}
```

You can do the same using `?:` operator:

```
int s = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
Random rand = s != 0 ? new Random(s) : new Random();

for(int i = 0;i < 20; i++){
    rand.next(1, 13);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to define `rand` in the scope you are intending to use it:

```
Console.WriteLine("Seedwaarde (optioneel)");
int s = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

Random rand;
if (s != 0 || s != null /*note this second condition will never be true*/)
{
   rand = new Random(s);
}
else
{
    rand = new Random();
}

for(int i = 0;i < 20; i++)
{
    rand.next(1, 13);
}
```

---

In the snippet posted in the question you are defining a new *local* `rand` in each of the if-block and else-block, which immediately fall out of scope as soon as the block is exited, and presumably find their way to the garbage bin shortly thereafter.

Comment: Would not a // comment after the closing bracket be preferable to a /* */ comment within the statement?

Comment: @stuartd I wanted to put it inline with the condition itself, but you're probably right.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to declare the rand variable out of the scope of the if statements

```
    Console.WriteLine("Seedwaarde (optioneel)");
    int s = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
    Random rand;
    if (s != 0 || s != null)
    {

      rand = new Random(s);

    }
    else
    {

        rand = new Random();

    }

    for(int i = 0;i < 20; i++){

        rand.next(1, 13);

    }
```

Comment: sorry didn't have a ; at the end of the variable declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Declare it earlier.

```
    Console.WriteLine("Seedwaarde (optioneel)");
    int s = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
    Random rand;
    if (s != 0 || s != null)
    {

       rand = new Random(s);

    }
    else
    {

        rand = new Random();

    }

    for(int i = 0;i < 20; i++){

        rand.next(1, 13);

    }
```